# Updating a mongoDb collection on Nested Arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a json like this. I want to add an agent to technical `departmentName` just like how it is there in support. I have been trying with `$push` and add to set but it didn't help.

This is what I have tried:

```
var depName = "Support"; // i get this from a form
db.collection('departments').update(
    { "departments.departmentName": depName },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            "departmentName": depName,
            "agents": {
                "agentName": "xxx", 
                "agentNumber": "xxx"
            }
        }
    }, function(err,result) { }
);
```

and this

```
db.collection('departments').update(
    { "departments.departmentName": depName },
    { 
        $addToSet: {
            "agents": {
                "agentName": "xxx", 
                "agentNumber": "xxx"
            }
        }
    }, function(err,result) { }
);
```

I would like to how to write a query for this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "578f6377dcba0f1ad368b7bb"
    },
    "name": "xxx",
    "departments": [
        {
            "departmentName": "Support",
            "agents": [
                {
                    "agentName": "xxx",
                    "agentNumber": "xxx"
                },
                {
                    "agentName": "xxx",
                    "agentNumber": "xxx"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "departmentName": "Technical"
        },
        {
            "departmentName": "Customer Care"
        }
    ]
}
```

The end result should look like this:

```
 {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "578f6377dcba0f1ad368b7bb"
    },
    "name": "xxx",
    "departments": [
        {
            "departmentName": "Support",
            "agents": [
                {
                    "agentName": "xxx",
                    "agentNumber": "xxx"
                },
                {
                    "agentName": "xxx",
                    "agentNumber": "xxx"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "departmentName": "Technical",
            "agents": [
                {
                    "agentName": "xxx",
                    "agentNumber": "xxx"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "departmentName": "Customer Care"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [**`$ positional operator`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in your update as follows:

```
db.collection('departments').update(
    { "departments.departmentName": depName },
    { 
        "$addToSet": {
            "departments.$.agents": {
                "agentName": "foo", 
                "agentNumber": "123"
            }
        }
    }, function (err, result) {}
)
```

This enables you to identify an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.